# Difference between 授業を受ける and 授業を取る

Tags: word-choice

I've seen both:

> 授業を受ける
>
> 授業を取る

Meaning:

> "Take a class"

Is there a difference in usage, nuance, or meaning?

For example, if I want to write:

> He/she will probably take the beginner's class.
> (ビギナーの授業を受ける・取るかもしれません。)

which would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"授業を受ける" refers to the act of being in class while a class is in session. You should mentally picture you being in a classroom at the very moment when the teaching is going on.

"授業を取る" on the other hand refers to the act of registering for a class, for a semester for example. It need not involve your being present in a classroom.